# How to call awakeFromnib again & again, i am using setNeedsDisplay ,it is not working

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

while loading view First time awakeFromNib is called, but i want to call awakeFromNib again through method.

i have tried [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
but it is not calling awakeFromNib again

Can any one suggest why is not calling awakeFromnib
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

`setNeedsDisplay:YES` is used to redraw the view it does not call awakeFromNib.

You can move all the codes of `[self awakeFromNib];` to other method and call those from awakeFromNib and later when ever you want to restart.

Comment: You should not directly call `awakeFromNib`. That method being called means a specific thing; calling it in any other circumstance is piling multiple meanings onto a single method. Move the stuff you want to do in both circumstances to another method, and call that from both places.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is bigger then just fixing awakeFromNib. The real problem is there is no method in NSViewController that tells the controller when the view is loaded. What I typically do is extend NSViewController and add a controllerHasFocus method. And the class that handles swapping views will send controllerHasFocus. Then it will act sort of like viewDidLoad in iOS. There are a number of discussions that probably explain this better than I did, if you search for them on SO.